# Firebase modules failed to initialize: remote_config (missing dependency)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-analytics

Lately I've been getting quite some of these crashes:

```
java.lang.Exception: InitializationException :   Firebase modules failed to initialize: remote_config (missing dependency)
       at Firebase.FirebaseApp.CreateAndTrack(Firebase.FirebaseApp)
       at Firebase.FirebaseApp.Create(Firebase.FirebaseApp)
       at Firebase.FirebaseApp.get_DefaultInstance(Firebase.FirebaseApp)
       at Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics..cctor(Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.)
       at Titan.Managers.GameManager.Awake(Titan.Managers.GameManager)
```

On Awake I'm only calling this: `Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.SetUserId(udid);`

Does anyone know what might be the problem here? We were also unable to reproduce this issue.

Comment: I get them too (for messaging instead of remote_config). I think these aren't crashes exactly though (Crashlytics categorises them as non-fatal). It also happens for only a subset of our users, which is a bit surprising since I would expect a missing dependency to either be there or not.

Answer (score 1):

it can be cause because you are testing an emulator doen't have google api (google play services) installed, check that you choose an image with google api or
you have an old Google play services (below 9.0.0)

Comment: This are crashes from users that downloaded game via google play store, so they have to have google play services installed, am I right? And only about 1% of users are having this issue.

Comment: Hey thanks so much! This was it. I didn't have an account signed in to my play store because I factory reset my device.