# How to resolve 'missing dependency' error with firebase and unity3d

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I am integrating firebase with my unity3d project. I have imported the DB & Auth Assets from the firebase SDK v5.6.1  using the custom import option. I am able to connect to firebase using the editor and also after generating a windows application.

However, when I connect through the android simulator (or iOS for that matter) after generating an APK, I see the following error in the log:

> InitializationException:  Firebase modules failed to initialize: auth (missing dependency), database (missing dependency)
>
> @ Firebase.FirebaseApp.CreateAndTrack (Firebase.FirebaseApp+CreateDelegate createDelegate, Firebase.FirebaseApp existingProxy)
> @ Firebase.FirebaseApp.Create () [0x00027] in :0

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Tried the following:

- New project from scratch with no other packages/assets loaded
- Latest android development studio installed
- Latest Unity3d
- Enable an email/password connection to my firebase project.
- Run Resolve and Force Resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are testing on an emulator that doesn't have google API (google play services) installed, check that you choose a device image with Google API.
Same topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43273647/firebase-modules-failed-to-initialize-remote-config-missing-dependency).